# How to set custom screen resolution with xrandr (output - default)

Tags: video, resolution, xrandr

I need to set some fancy resolution, like 700x500, 320x860, 400x400 etc. The problem is that the output of the device is not recognized, so it's set to default. But when I add a newmode to xrandr it warns that "Failed to get size of gamma for output default". And after I add the new mode to default output, xrandr fails to set the new resolution, responding "Configure crtc 0 failed". 
How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not every mode is possible. [Here](http://www.mythtv.org/wiki/Modeline_Database) you can get nice example of some possible custom modelines. Still every modeline is not supported by every video card or monitor.

Comment: xrandr rounds the resolution that user wants to add to some possible value. but that's not the point of my question

Comment: As I said not every imaginable mode is possible. This is already hardware limitation. For instance width is usually multiple of 8 or more. Similar rules exists for number of lines (based on how this data is organized in memory chips).